# Stopping scanner timeout when large number of cells

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata, apache-crunch

I have a crunch job where a cell can contain hundreds of thousands of cells (the data is split into rows keyed by location+time. For certain locations and times there can be lots of cells). The job processes each cell, but I get a scanner timeout when the number of cells is very large.

I can increase the timeouts e.g. hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period, but they have to be huge values (hours since a single cell can take 200ms) which doesn't seem ideal.

I thought I could use scan.setAllowPartialResults() and scan.setMaxResultSize(), but that only works if scan.getFilter().hasFilterRow() is false, which in my case it isn't. I also saw scanner.setMaxNumRows(), but I can't see any way to get to the scanner from crunch.

I could write all the data out to a temp location and then process it in the reduce, but that seems wrong. I feel I must be missing something about how this should be done.

How should a crunch job handle the situation where it has to process a huge number of cells without timing out?
Thanks.

Comment: hbase cell does not contain rows. row is a key and several cells - for each column family:qualifier:version.  did you mean row has a lot of columns?

Comment: Whoop, sorry. I meant cells. The data is split into rows with a key of location+time. For certain locations and times there can be lots of cells.

Comment: I'm afraid there's nothing that can be done with this table design

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks.